# How to switch to a new publisher when previous one failed or broken?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Assume there are three entities:

- `Supplier of Mono<ValuesSource>` - supplier of `ValuesSource` publishers
- `ValuesSource` - publisher of values
- value (their nature is not important, i.e. `String`)

Intention is:

1. take next source from supplier
2. create publisher retrieving values from the source
3. for each response return current values-publisher
4. if current source fails to produce next value (throws an error or returns Mono.error) go to step (1)

**What is the proper way to switch to a new `ValuesSource`, when the previous one failed?**

---

```
class ValuesService {

  private ValuesSource source;
  private Mono<String> valuesPublisher;

  NumbersGeneratorServiceImpl(Supplier<Mono<ValuesSource>> sourcesSupplier) {
    var currentSource = sourcesSupplier.get();
    this.valuesPublisher= Mono.defer(() -> source.flatMap(s -> s.makeNextValue()));                        
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<Object> nextValue() {
    // how to detect if publisher failed to publish a value
    // and create a new publisher with new source from sourcesSupplier.get()
    return valuesPublisher;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `ValueSource`? Why does the default constructor have a different name from the class? Where is  currentSource used?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense at the moment (to me at least.) Can you post a [mcve] that causes the error you want to recover from?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you want to do, but if I understand correctly and you want to obtain from supplier you can just use

[Mono#retry](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retry-)

Replaced ValueSource with String since it isn't clear what you want to do with it from the question, but it doesn't affect logic anyway.

```
class ValuesService{

    private Mono<String> valuesPublisher;

    ValuesService(Supplier<Mono<String>> sourcesSupplier) {

        this.valuesPublisher =
                //Every subscription calls get on supplier
                Mono.defer(sourcesSupplier)
                        //Retry when error, resubsribes each time
                        .retry();
    }

    Mono<String> getValuesPublisher(){
        return valuesPublisher;

    }
}
```